# Suma De Campos (INPUT)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo HTML,Necesito sumar los 4 campos que se ven ahí, monto 1, monto2, monto3 , y monto4 y que se muestre la suma en el input valor total .
Si se va borrando algun valor que se elimine del valor total .

```html
<table class="table-form-mp">
  <tr>

    <td width="33%">
      <dx:ASPxLabelID="LbMonto1" runat="server" OnInit="Page_Load" ClientInstanceName="LbMonto1" CssClass="obligatorio_lbl_css" SkinID="default_lbl" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333">
        </dx:ASPxLabel>
        <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_1" />
    </td>
    <td width="34%">
      <dx:ASPxLabel ID="LbMonto2" runat="server" OnInit="Page_Load" ClientInstanceName="LbMonto2" CssClass="obligatorio_lbl_css" SkinID="default_lbl" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333">
      </dx:ASPxLabel>
      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_2" />
    </td>
    <td width="33%">
      <dx:ASPxLabel ID="LbMonto3" runat="server" OnInit="Page_Load" ClientInstanceName="LbMonto3" CssClass="obligatorio_lbl_css" SkinID="default_lbl" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333">
      </dx:ASPxLabel>
      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%">
      <span class="obligatorio_lbl_css">Monto Otras Vigencias</span>
      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_4" />
    </td>
    <td width="34%">
      <span class="default_lbl_css">Valor Total</span>

      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt" style="width: 223px" id="MontoTotal" />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: ¿La suma se tiene que dar al instante?

Comment: saludos , Si debe dar al instante

Comment: function sumar(c){
var subtotal = 0;
campo = c.form;
  if(!/^\d*$/.test(c.value)) return;

      for (var i = 0; i < campo.length-1; i++) {
          if (!/^\d+$/.test(campo[i].value)) continue;
              subtotal += parseInt(campo[i].value);
          }
       if (input.value < 0) {
        
document.getElementById('res').value = subtotal;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es asignar un evento `keyup` a los `input` que se usaran para la suma de valores. Cada que se ejecute el evento debes capturar el valor de los 4 `input` y sumarlos para asignarlos al quinto.

Usando **jQuery** Sería así:

```js
$("input").not("#MontoTotal").keyup(function(){
  var Monto_1 = Number($("#Monto_1").val());
  var Monto_2 = Number($("#Monto_2").val());
  var Monto_3 = Number($("#Monto_3").val());
  var Monto_4 = Number($("#Monto_4").val());
  
  var suma = Monto_1 + Monto_2 + Monto_3 + Monto_4;
  
  $("#MontoTotal").val(suma);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-form-mp">
  <tr>

    <td width="33%">
      <dx:ASPxLabelID="LbMonto1" runat="server" OnInit="Page_Load" ClientInstanceName="LbMonto1" CssClass="obligatorio_lbl_css" SkinID="default_lbl" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333">
        </dx:ASPxLabel>
        <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt monto" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_1" />
    </td>
    <td width="34%">
      <dx:ASPxLabel ID="LbMonto2" runat="server" OnInit="Page_Load" ClientInstanceName="LbMonto2" CssClass="obligatorio_lbl_css" SkinID="default_lbl" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333">
      </dx:ASPxLabel>
      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt monto" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_2" />
    </td>
    <td width="33%">
      <dx:ASPxLabel ID="LbMonto3" runat="server" OnInit="Page_Load" ClientInstanceName="LbMonto3" CssClass="obligatorio_lbl_css" SkinID="default_lbl" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#333333">
      </dx:ASPxLabel>
      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt monto" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%">
      <span class="obligatorio_lbl_css">Monto Otras Vigencias</span>
      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt monto" style="width: 223px" id="Monto_4" />
    </td>
    <td width="34%">
      <span class="default_lbl_css">Valor Total</span>

      <input type="text" class="default_tb_css amt" style="width: 223px" id="MontoTotal" />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Saludos veo que funciona bien , pero la aplicacion solo tiene jquery 1.7

Comment: @KristianEspitia en este caso la versión no es problema debido a que los métodos que se están utilizando también hacen parte de la que mencionas, he editado mi respuesta y he bajado la versión de jQuery para que puedas apreciarlo.

Comment: Tengo una duda el .monto de donde lo llama en los input

Comment: @KristianEspitia es una clase que les agregué: class="default_tb_css amt monto"

Comment: Como te explico eso esta muy amarrado que los css solo cogen con su clase al insertarlo en mi codigo no me funciona , hay alguna manera de hacerlo por el id

Comment: @KristianEspitia ya actualicé los selectores de la respuesta

Comment: GRACIAS!!! Eres un maquina